# ProgrammingError: SQL syntax near "[" meaning?

Tags: python, mysql

Could someone please explain what this means?

```
 ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
 your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[' at line 1
```

Is it that somewhere in my code near "[" i've done something wrong?

The error is occurring in this block of code. I don't understand why it's saying that it's near "[" as that piece of code was working fine beforehand? Thank you

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
p_list = []
n_list = []
h_list = []
ba_list = []
be_list = []
all_var =[]

for page in range(20,300,20):
    my_url = "https://www.daft.ie/ireland/property-for-sale/? 
 offset=20".format(page)

#open connection and grab webpage
uClient = uReq(my_url)
#store html in a variable
page_html = uClient.read() 
#close web connection
uClient.close()
#parse html
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
print(soup)

#grabs listings house information
listings = soup.findAll("div", 
{"class":"FeaturedCardPropertyInformation__detailsContainer"})

for container in listings:
#extracting price
    price = container.div.div.strong.text
    price = price.strip('AMV: €')
    price = price.strip('Reserve: €')
    price = price.replace(',', "")
    price = int(price)
    p_list.append(price)

    #location
    location = container.div.find("a {"class":"PropertyInformationCommonStyles__addressCopy--link"}).text
    n_list.append("'"+location+"'")
    #house type
    house = container.div.find("div", 
  {"class":"QuickPropertyDetails__propertyType"}).text
    h_list.append("'"+house+"'")
    #number of bathrooms
    bath_num = container.div.find("div {"class":"QuickPropertyDetails__iconCopy--WithBorder"}).text
    #makes str and int
    bath_num = int(bath_num)
    ba_list.append(bath_num)
        #number of bedrooms
    bed_num = container.div.find("div", {"class":"QuickPropertyDetails__iconCopy"}).text
    bed_num = int(bed_num)
    be_list.append(bed_num)
    #makes str and int
    all_var.append((price, location, house, bath_num, bed_num))
    a_v = str(all_var)
   #connecting to database     
    import mysql.connector

d_b = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "myaccount", passwd = "mypassword", database = "database",)

print(d_b)
mycursor = d_b.cursor(buffered=True)
#create database
#mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE daftdatabase")
#create table
#mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE DaftTable(price Integer(10), location 
VARCHAR(50), type VARCHAR(20), bedrooms INTEGER(2),  bathrooms 
INTEGER(2))")
show_t = mycursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")


for var in a_v:
    data = mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO DaftTable(price, location, type, bathrooms, bedrooms) VALUES"+var)
    mycursor.commit()
```

Every time I do fix an error another one keeps occurring and I just want to understand what the error is telling me and how I can fix it?

Comment: ...Maybe posting your SQL would be a good idea?

Comment: @ChatterOne I've appended the code onto the question now but i'm also looking to try to learn what the error is telling me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you're composing SQL the wrong way.

First of all you should escape/sanitize whatever it is you're inserting.
If you compose the string like that, at best there's a high chance that at some point it'll fail (because of an unescaped single quote, for example), at worst if you do this in other parts of your code, you'll have a SQL injection vulnerability

Second, even if you escaped everything, it would still not work.

You're taking the values, putting them in a list, and then you stringify it:

```
all_var.append((price, location, house, bath_num, bed_num))
a_v = str(all_var)
```

This means that if you have something like

```
[
    (1, 2, 3, 4),
    (5, 6, 7, 8),
]
```

for your values, you're converting this to the string `[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)]` and your `for` loop will iterate over the single characters of this string.

The first character is the `[` that is giving you the error, because you're trying to execute

`INSERT INTO DaftTable(price, location, type, bathrooms, bedrooms) VALUES[")`

So, what you need is to NOT stringify the values and compose your string in a proper way (if you REALLY want to compose the string instead of using some type of SQL library, at least use the `%s` syntax).

Comment: Thanks I understand why the error is being given now but I'm getting confused in terms of composing the string in the proper way? How would you compose a string from a list and feed it into a SQL database? Thank you.

Comment: @Adrian_Lopez This might help: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql-insert/